# Question about a robocode method containing sinus and cosinus

Tags: trigonometry

I recently started coding courses while my math is really lagging behind beceuse of my past. I'm currently working on the Robocode program but I don't understand the Sine and Cosine example in one of the examples.

Can someone explain me what this lines of code really do?
This is what the master robot does:

```
// Calculate enemy bearing
    double enemyBearing = this.getHeading() + e.getBearing();
    // Calculate enemy's position
    double enemyX = getX() + e.getDistance() * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(enemyBearing));
    double enemyY = getY() + e.getDistance() * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(enemyBearing));

        // Send enemy position to teammates
        broadcastMessage(new Point(enemyX, enemyY));
```

This is what the droidrobots will recieve:

```
Point p = (Point) e.getMessage();
            // Calculate x and y to target
            double dx = p.getX() - this.getX();
            double dy = p.getY() - this.getY();
            // Calculate angle to target
            double theta = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(dx, dy));

            // Turn gun to target
            turnGunRight(normalRelativeAngleDegrees(theta - getGunHeading()));
```

Sorry for my probably simple question. I can't figure it out.

Full code here: https://github.com/robo-code/robocode/tree/master/robocode.samples/src/main/java/sampleteam

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier for you if you would make a sketch. Let's use three points on a 2D grid (marked with North, South, East, and West). The first point, say $(x_1,y_1)$ is your ship. The enemy is at $(x_2,y_2)$, and your droid is at $(x_3,y_3)$. Your ship is oriented at an angle with respect to the North direction. This is given by `this.getHeading()`. In the coordinate system of your ship, the position of the enemy is at distance `e.getDistance()`, in the direction `e.getBearing()` with respect to your forward direction. That's equivalent of saying that the enemy ship is at distance `e.getDistance()`, at an angle `enemyBearing` with respect to the North direction. Then the position of the enemy ship in Cartesian coordinates with respect to your ship are $$e_x=e_d\sin e_B\\e_y=e_d\cos e_B$$ 
Here $e_d$ is the distance to the enemy ship, and $e_B$ is the true direction with respect to North. To find out the absolute position, you need to add the position of your ship.

The second part is doing the same steps in reverse.